# Reload parent window on subdomain from popup

Tags: javascript, popup, cross-domain, dom-events

How can I reload the parent page in this scenario:

```
Parent domain: sub.abc.com
Popup domain: abc.com
```

Using `window.opener.location.reload();` from the popup only works when the domains are equal (should also when the popup is a subdomain of parent).

I have tried to reload on `onunload` event in parent:

```
var targetWin = window.open(...
targetWin.onunload = function(){ 
    window.location.reload(); 
};
```

This triggers too early, probably since the popup redirects.

I have also tried to explicitly set the domain in parent like this:

```
document.domain = "abc.com";
```

This has no effect, I still get the error

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
> http‍://sub.example.com/ from frame with URL http‍://example.com. Domains, protocols and
> ports must match.

Do I have to resort to some hideous polling function to check if `targetWin.closed == true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been up for two weeks and i have come to the conclusion that there is no way of doing this without polling.

The reason, as stated in the question, is that the parent is a sub domain of the popup.